# Is it possible to have a custom boolean object that inherits from Boolean.prototype?

Tags: javascript

Something in the lines of:

```
  var MyCustomBoolean = function(b){
    if (b === 'FALSE'){
      this.b = false;
    }else if(b === 'TRUE'){
      this.b = true;
    }

    this.valueOf = function(){
      return this.b;
    }
  }
```

so that the following would produce a single alert with the text "in your face"

```
if (new MyCustomBoolean('TRUE')){
  alert("In your face!");
}

if (new MyCustomBoolean('FALSE')){
  alert("not so much.");
}
```

Now i can work around this by explicitly calling the valueOf function or. by checking equivalence through "myBObj == true".

So is it possible to have a custom boolean object that inherits from Boolean.prototype such that i could write if blocks as described above?

Comment: What purpose would this object serve?

Comment: As a lexer type where internally i would use its true/false values in a variety of if checks, and externally it would display as TRUE/FALSE through toString and have a value of 0/1 through valueOf()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to have any objects that evaluate to `false`. Inheriting from 
`Boolean.prototype` will not change the [`ToBoolean` behaviour](http://es5.github.com/#x9.2). Instead, make all your lexer objects implement a kind of "evaluate" method, so that the following would work:

```
var bool = new LexerBoolean("FALSE")
if (bool.getSemanticValue()) {…}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's not as readable as i would have liked, but i guess it can't be helped.